# Dynamic es6 module import names

Tags: dynamic, module, ecmascript-6

I would like to import a module who's file location is dynamic.

For example, I want a library dir to be prepended to the module name:

```
import foo from 'lib/'+'utils';
```

This apparently is not allowed, the syntax does not allow a calculated import name.

I have a similar situation with a single html file that imports arbitrary programs gotten from the query string as the variable "main", say.  This also seems to fail:

```
import program from main; // var main = 'square-program';
```

How do I manage "dynamic" module names?

Comment: The entire system of ES6 module imports and exports is designed to allow static analysis of dependencies, and for good reason cannot do what you want. `import` is not `require`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Uh, I want a es6 gold badge now :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Working on it :D (I don't even have a bronze badge yet...)